# jQuery - why doesn't attr.src change?

Tags: jquery

I have an image that when click I want to have changed and then have the browser jump to a new URL.  I'm using .one so that the user can only click the image once.

```
     jQuery('#launch_button').one('click', function() {
      jQuery("#launch_button").attr("src", "images/button_launch2_grey.png");
      window.location.href = 'test.html';
     });
```

If I comment out the window.location.href the image changes properly.  If I do the opposite and comment out the attr change the window.location.href works but the image does not change first.  How do I get the first line (attr change) to finish/work before doing the window.location.href?

Comment: You are leaving the page before the image loads. You can try setting a timeout, but then you won't know if the timeout is long enough for the image to load. You could try a different approach - creating an `img` and only after it loads, set a timeout for the redirection.

Comment: thanks, settimeout worked, it allows the image to change and then the location.href will go.  test.html takes 10 seconds to load thats why I want the image change and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

When you're running `window.location.href` your *changing* the page the user is viewing.

Changes you make to the DOM will only persist for the current page; as soon as the user navigates away, the changes are lost.

The redirection to `test.html` should be *near* instantaneous. The image must first load before it is rendered. You should include the image in the DOM in a hidden `<img />` tag to ensure it is loaded before you show it (or preload it by constructing a `new Image()` and setting it's `src` to the image in JavaScript); but even then you're only going to see it for a split second.

Comment: How do I use jQuery to change the attr.src to an already preloaded image?

For example does this constitute a preloaded image?:
<div style='display:none'><img src='images/button_launch2_grey.png' id='launchbuttongrey'/></div>

And if so how do I use this to display it?
jQuery("#launch_button").attr("src", ??? );

Comment: @Ken: Yes, that's preloading the image. All you need to do is set the `src` attribute to the image URL. This works because the `button_launch2_grey.png` image has already been loaded by the hidden image; and so does not need to be loaded again.